# Why does Tomcat resolve context path differently for certain url-mappings?

Tags: tomcat, rest, servlets, url-mapping, staticresource

So, I'm trying to write a servlet which can handle a url mapping like:

> ```
> domain/context/servlet/resource_id
> ```

Before, when I was specifying the url pattern, I was just doing:

> /myServlet

But, for what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm doing...

> /myServlet/*

**THE PROBLEM I'M RUNNING INTO**:

I've been using relative path (so, just the file location with respect to my WebContent folder) for my static files (css/js/etc) now that I'm using the `/myServlet/*` mapping, the requests for the all static files are now being handled by myServlet.  So, basically, the static resources are now resolving to:

> domain/context/myServlet/relative_path_I_provide

as opposed to

> domain/context/relative_path_I_provide

I'm sure I can fix this myself by just building the absolute path for the resource as opposed to relying on the relative path; but I'm just wondering, why is the resolved path for the static resource changing when I'm using `/myServlet/*` url pattern as opposed to `/myServlet` ?

EDIT:

My folder structure is like

```
WebContent
   |
   |
   |-- debug
         |
         |-- css
              |
              |-- file.css
```

and I'm adding them in a link tag like:

```
<link href="debug/css/file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: How are you specifying the relative path for these static resources?

Comment: That explains it - please see my answer for why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that explains it. You're using a relative URL with no path information which means the browser resolves it to same directory as the resource that includes these URLs. When your servlet was mapped to `/myServlet`, it didn't appear in the path as a 'directory' i.e. it was the final resource being referred to.

Thus, your URL for the servlet was of the form `domain/context/myServlet` and so these relative URLs would also resolve to `domain/context/`.

But now, with a mapping of the form `/myServlet/*`, the servlet appears as a directory in the URL which means that when you go to `domain/context/myServlet/resource_id`, the relative URLs are resolved to the same directory as `resource_id` which is `domain/context/servlet/`.

See [this for more](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)

The fix might be one of the following:

1. Use relative URLs that are relative to the root of the application i.e. which begin with `/`. However, this would require you to put in the context path for your application in your code which means you can never simply deploy it with a different name without having to change everything. In short, don't do this.
2. Use relative URLs with path information in the form of `../` which will cause the URLs to resolve to a directory one level up. This is also brittle and will break if someone decides to map the resources to URLs of the form `domain/context/myServlet/secondLevel/resource_id`.
3. Create relative URLs that are relative to the context-path of the application. You can do this by setting your `href` values as `request.getContextPath + "/css/files/file.css"`. This will prepend the context-path to the beginning of each link's `href` thus, for  request for `domain/context/myServlet/resource_id`, this will become `/context/css/files/file.css` and resolve as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Has your actual URL changed before and after the url pattern change?
i.e. are you now invoking `http://domain/context/myServlet/something` instead of `http://domain/context/myServlet`

If the answer is yes, then it explains why the static files are now resolving to `http://domain/context/myServlet/static_file` 
(For the same reason why everything was resolving relative to the context in the earlier URL)

Comment: Yes, the url being invoked has changed, but there was no string difference in the resulting link tag used to load the css.  See my edit.